# AWS RDC - Sql Developer, Unable to connect

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have created an oracle database instance in RDS. The connection was created successfully. I was trying to connect via SQL developer, but seems i am not able to connect.

**Get the error as: io error the network adapter could not establish the connection.**

The username, password and the oracle instance name is correct. Also, the hostname is correct as well. please find the attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG02o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyzO8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ1gN.png)

Comment: Instead of SID=orcl, try SERVICE_NAME=orcl

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I did try that, its off no use.